# Create a full width header with diagonal background color

Tags: html, css, background

What I'm going to explain is a little complicated, so I made an image hoping it could help us.

[image]
*Here is the [large image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/usldqi0tl4j4fbt/Senza%20titolo-12.png).*

In the top part of the page there is an header. It must have some characteristics:

1. it have to be full width but...
2. its content (the logo and the menu) is wrapped in a centered div, `960px` of width

   these two points are simple: I create an header with a fixed height and a `100%` width, then a div with `960px` of width and margin `0 auto` so that it's always centered.

   Now it comes the difficulties:
3. the background color, as you can see, is transparent, in fact we see the photo under the header. And this transparency is not the same for all the header: the side in which I should locate the logo has a certain value of opacity, and the side of menu has another value. And, moreover, the two sides are separated by a diagonal line.

It seems to be easy, but I don't find a solution to set the background in the way it appears in the image without having problems.

Comment: where is your trying source code??

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. You want the 'menu items' part to be transparent as seen in the image? what have you tried? could you post your code?

Comment: How are you creating the transparent background and the diagonal line (through code, an image, etc)? The code you have would be good so we can see how to best make this happen, there are various ways to do so.

Comment: I'm creating the website through wordpress and in local and on my local machine, this is the reason why I didn't wrote the source code. Anyway, now i'm cleaning the code and creating an html example.

Comment: @robooneus oh, my god: thanks to you. Because I tried creating the background with Illustrator and putting it in the header. But it didn't work because when I resized the screen it was not centered. But while I was reading your words and then replying to you I thought [.oO("background-position: center center") -.-'] and now it works all fine.

Comment: @marco glad to have been of some help :P Happy coding.

Comment: @marco: please don't put any sort of "solved" marker in your titles. If you've found a solution to your problem, please post it as an answer when you can so future visitors can benefit too.

Comment: @Mat ok Mat, sorry but I'm a new user here

Comment: @marco: that's fine, don't worry about it. These sites have quite a few "rules" that are very different from usual forums. You'll get used to it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS solution.

### Update Version:

To implement full-width multiple colored header, I changed my mind and decided to use [CSS3 Gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient), Nowadays all modern web browsers support [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), but can use a transparent image or `SVG` as fallback for old browsers.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">right side</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.header {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-20deg, rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5), rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3));
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(-20deg, rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5), rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3));
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(-20deg, rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5), rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3));
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(-20deg, rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5), rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3));
  background:         linear-gradient(110deg, rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5), rgba(230, 0, 200, 0.5) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3) 40%, rgba(200, 0, 200, 0.3));

  min-width: 960px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 2px dashed green; /* Just for demo */
}

.left, .right {
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 350px;
}
```

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/oMUyuNI/4)**.

### Previous Answer:

I've used `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to implement the bevel corners. You can simply transparent image instead, if you want to support old IE versions.

**CSS:**

```css
.left, .right {
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 200, 0, .5);
}

.right {
  background-color: rgba(255, 150, 0, .5);
  margin-left: 225px;
}

.left:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(255, 200, 0, .5) transparent transparent transparent;
  border-width: 35px 25px 0 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -25px;
}

.right:before {
  content: ' ';
  display: block;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(255, 150, 0, .5) transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 35px 25px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -25px;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/oMUyuNI/1/edit)**

Comment: I solved in an other way but I'm really curious to know: how did you obtain the diagonal line beetwen the divs?

Comment: These two `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are two right-angled triangles that are sticking together and make a rectangle. and `.left` and `.right` division are placed around them.

Comment: That's a fantastic solution

Comment: @marco I've updated my answer, you might want to consider the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS color property can be used by rgba method.

```
background:rgba(RED,GREEN,BLUE,OPACITY);
```

For example if you want to make background red with an opacity of of 50% then you have to use the following code.

```
background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

Things you must know

- the maximum value for color (red green or blue) is 255 while lowest value is 0.
- The highest value for opacity is 1 while lowest is 0.

Comment: I solved creating the background for the header (as a vector image) and then putting it as background of the header. And the most important (and simplest) part is to put "background-position: center top"